# How to lock ionic 3 website screen orientation in portrait mode for mobile browser

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, angular5

How to lock ionic 3 website screen orientation in Portrait mode while opening in mobile browser?

Can anyone please provide any suggestion on this?

Comment: I have used screen-orientation plugin for app. But I need to lock screen orientation of website in mobile browser. For website, I am not able to lock screen orientation with plugin and  <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible using any plugin. But can be achieved using mediaqueries. Try adding below CSS code in your .css file:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) and (orientation: 
landscape) {
  html {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: left top;
    width: 100vh;
    height: 100vw;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But do you have any idea how to lock mobile browser orientation because with CSS we can control our webpage only.

Comment: @Darshana, I am not getting what do you mean by "with CSS we can control our webpage only".

Comment: I mean with CSS we can lock orientation of our webpage but is it possible to lock orientation of mobile browser itself with any code?

Answer (score -1):

referring to the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/screen-orientation/), try to use this in your app.ts:

```
import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation';

constructor(private screenOrientation: ScreenOrientation) {  
   this.screenOrientation.lock(this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.PORTRAIT_PRIMARY);
}
```